# Othorgonal matrices and full rank

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse, diagonalization, orthogonal-matrices

I have a question regarding orthogonal matrices. Is it the case that orthogonal matrices always have full rank?

I tried to illustrate a $2\times 2$ orthogonal matrix with $\det=-1$ and come to the conclusion that it actually has full rank. However, I read in the text book that an orthogonal matrix with $\det=-1$ can be diagonizable or not. I do think this has something to do with the rank and hence invertibility.

Comment: It is not true that diagonalizability has "something to do with the rank" in the way that you are implying.  See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/765144/81360) for instance.

Comment: Doesn’t the fact that the determinant is nonzero immediately tell you that the matrix has full rank?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Indeed an orthogonal matrix has full rank. 
An Orthogonal matrix is a square matrix which has orthonormal columns. Consider an $n\times n$ orthogonal matrix with columns $q_1, q_2,...,q_n$. Since $q_i'$s are orthonormal, they are linearly independent (Can you prove it?). 
Hence the matrix has $n$ linearly independent columns. Therefore, rank of the matrix = $n$ = dimension of column space.

Answer (score 1):

The diagonalisability has nothing to do with invertibility. Orthogonal matrices always have full rank and so are always invertible. However they do not have to be diagonalisable. For instance, any $2\times 2$ rotation which is not $\pm \mathrm{Id}$ is represented by a $2\times 2$ orthogonal matrix which is invertible but not diagonalisable over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer. Could you might elaborate the rotation part a bit? My topic is actually eigenvalues and eigenvectors. However, I do not really see the point why an orthogonal matrix with det=1 can be diagonalized for sure and an orthogonal matrix with det=-1 cannot. I know that an orthogonal matrix with det=-1 can be geometrically seen as a reflection. But how do I argue that it is not diagonazible?

Comment: @randomname Don’t you have that backwards? As written in this answer, most $2\times2$ orthogonal matrices with determinant $1$ have complex eigenvalues and are **not** diagonalizable over the reals.

Answer (score 0):

As the previous replies have said, yes, they do! I think one could "remember" this fact geometrically by seeing that an orthogonal matrix is a rotation matrix, and so it won't ever zero out any vector; in other words, it doesn't have a null space.